# 451 4.4.2 Timeout waiting for data from client

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, swiftmailer

> [warning][yii\swiftmailer\Logger::add] !! Expected response code 250 but got code "451", with message "451 4.4.2 Timeout waiting for data from client

I have been getting this issue from last 2 months.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.